# How to open 3 emacs windows when debugging using gdb

Tags: debugging, gdb

I am debugging a program that outputs 8 or more lines of display and requires input.  So my IO window has to be say 10 rows or so in height.  But I also want to see the source code AND of course the gdb input window.

What is the easiest way to present this?  To have 3 windows?  1 for gdb, 1 for console and the other for the source code?  If so how do I get 3 windows?

Or if I could somehow get the gdb io window to be a separate console window that might be even better.

Comment: Do you want to split your Emacs frame into multiple windows? There's `C-x 2` and `C-x 3`. You can adjust window sizes with `C-x {`, `C-x }`, `C-x ^` and `C-x -`. You can also have multiple Emacs frames connected to the same Emacs instance.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else's benefit, you can use gdb-many-windows like:

1. Compile your executable (don't forget to compile with the -g flag).
2. m-x gdb
3. m-x gdb-many-windows

You then get the same sort of environment as you would find in developer IDE's.

Some links:
https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/GDB-User-Interface-Layout.html
https://undo.io/resources/gdb-watchpoint/using-gdb-emacs/

Answer (score 0):

To create a new console window you can do `C-x 5 b`  with an existing buffer or `C-x 5 f` to open a file.
To switch between the different consoles you can do `C-x 5 o`
You can then split each of the consoles into different frames horizontally by `C-x 2` or vertically by `C-x 3`

Comment: `C-x 5 b`, like `C-x b` and `C-x 4 b`, is not just for an existing buffer. It's also for creating a new buffer.